# If Statement within Views in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so i have been starting to get used to rails 3 over the past few days and have got a project in the works to test things out on. Is it possible to do the following or what would you suggest is the best way to only allow post authors to edit their posts.

```
<% if post.author_id == current_user.id %>
   <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You should check out the CanCan gem - it works very well to define permissions for situations like this. You define user abilities and can then use statements like `if can? :update, post`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommendation: Don't compare `id`s - compare objects.

```
<% if post.author == current_user %>
```

Optional: Consider using a plugin (only if necessary) like [`cancan`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to make it even more descriptive.

```
<% if can? :edit, post %>
```

Comment: I have tried using your top example, but on refreshing i got this error:

`undefined method `author'`

Comment: I believe he's assuming a many to many relationship with :has_many, etc.

Comment: Your Post model should contain a `belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User"` association to make that work.